# Поочередное нажатие button

Tags: javascript, button

Ребята как можно сделать чтоб при нажатии на кнопку она залилась зеленым цветом , при нажатии на вторую кнопку первая окрашивается в серый ,а вторая в зеленый ,если нажал на третюю то закрашивается зеленым ,а первая и вторая серым.

Вот принципе с чекбоксами только нужно чтоб еще кнопки заливались зеленым или серым цветом .

```js
$('#group input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('#group input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

```css
<style>
.checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
 line-height: 21px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="group" class="text-center">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox">checkbox 1</label><br>
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox">checkbox 2</label><br>
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox">checkbox 3</label>
</div>
<script src="//yandex.st/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы просто сделал доп. класс (active например) и при клике на кнопку у всех кнопок его убирал а нажатой добавлял и усе)

По логике как то так:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

А в стилях для активного класса пропиши заливку зеленым.